# Kibana Merge Multiple Fields to Single Bucket

Tags: kibana

My documents have both "src_ip" and "dest_ip" fields. I'd like a Vertical Bar  visualization of IP counts regardless of which field they are in. However...

- The X-Axis on Vertical Bar only allows selecting a single field, and it's unclear that Painless script supports merging arrays.
- The "Composite Aggregation" seems to support what I want, but can't be selected for the X-Axis.
- I'd also though I could just handle src_ip and dest_ip separately, perhaps aligning their colors so multiple stacks would look like one bar, but it seems I can only define a single X-Axis per chart.

Can someone suggest a workaround?